# Overriding radio styling in CSS, without direct access due to shortcode use Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I'm using WordPress and Propertyhive plugin to develop a property development website.

Because I'm using a custom theme, I need to use shortcodes provided by the propertyhive plugin to generate the correct parts on different pages.

The search box here (https://managemyrentaluk.com/our-properties/) doesn't style very well - I've managed to over-write some of the CSS to style the drop-downs better, but the radio input labels don't stack.

Any idea what I can do? Other than using Elementor to overwrite the CSS, I can't edit the source CSS as that's controlled by the plugin.

Thanks in advance.

I've tried overwriting CSS but I suspect there's some conflict going on that I can't get to the bottom of - any advice welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
/*---- To make your form inline-flex and make items centered vertically -----*/
form[name='ph_property_search']{
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}

/*----- To position your radio elements over and under without wrapping -----*/
.control.control-department {
    display: grid;
}
.control.control-department label {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to display block the labels.

```css
.property-search-form .control.control-department label {
  display: block;
}
```